# how does my laptop locate its domain controller if the DNS server is change

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I have around 50 computers joined to DomainA in branch office A and will be move to a temporarily branch office B

Branch office B has a different subnet and DNS servers which belong to a different domain - Domain B

Office A and B network are connected and routable to each other

I do not want to change the 50 computers DHCP automatic setup so those 50 computers are going to get DNS servers that belong to branch office B

What should i input in Domain B DNS servers such that those domainA/computers know how to find the DomainA DC ?

I read up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/how-domain-controllers-are-located but i am not sure what are the records that should be included

is it just these 2 records ?

```
_ldap._tcp.domainB

_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domainB
```

Should i create any folder in the DNS ? when i create an SRV record - i am able to choose msdcs as service and tcp as protocol but i am not able to make the record -> _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domainB

Should i just create a conditional fowarder for domainA in domainB DNS servers ?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into either delegation or forwarding.

Comment: mostly, if its a global network, and both sites can ping each other, why don't you just fetch one client and test the login?

Comment: You can set up DNS conditional forwarding on the domain B DNS servers to forward any domainA DNS requests to domainA DNS servers. Then you'll need to confirm firewalls are open between sites to allow all the necessary DNS and AD authentication traffic.